# Data synchronization between two or Android devices and website

Tags: android, synchronization

I am building an app that allows users to insert data and synchronize with website. User can insert data on the website as well. There are two entity tables (`T1` and `T2`) and one N-M relation table (`TR`).

Data Structure (it's just illustrative):

```
T1 (_id, name, modified)
T2 (_id, name, modified)
TR (t1_id, t2_id)
```

The problem I am facing is data synchronization of IDs. E.g. Device A1 and A2 are offline and record is inserted on both, with the ID = 1. After they are online sync starts and there is a conflict with IDs. I thought about introducing an extra column `gid` - something like global ID. So the structure would be:

```
T1 (_id, name, modified, gid)
T2 (_id, name, modified, gid)
TR (t1_id, t2_id, t1_gid, t2_gid)
```

Global ID would be assigned by website.

But I not sure whether this is a good approach or not (never done anything like this before and cannot tell if there will be any future problem).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use additional ids, suppose network_id, generate all network_ids on the server and use local ids on devices (e.g. UUID). When you are sending create entity request server will generate a real id and return it to you, so you can update a local database with network_id. It is important to use network_id as main field and local_id only if you don't have network_id.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So if I understand that right the `network_id` is my `gid` which should be regular primary key on the server. But what about the relations? I'd have to return both `network_id`-s to update relation row locally. Or I don't need to because the relation will be saved on device with local ids and on server with the network ids - number values would be different, but the relation itself would be preserved. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But for avoiding unpredictable bugs it will be better to add network ids (your global ids) to relations. Because when you will change relation on server, e.g. adding a new relation of item which didn't exist before to existing item it can produce some problems which will be difficult to debug. So better to have all data similar. Since you have network id of item in your device - there is no need in local id

Comment: Ok, so I'll have `network_id` on my local device, so the table structure will be same as I've mentioned above (second block of code). But on the server, there is no need to store local ids, just regular `id` which will be `network_id` for local devices after upload.